# rails upgrade from 4.0.3 to 4.2.0 cannot load such file error

Tags: sidekiq, sentry, raven, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I try to upgrade my rails app from 4.0.3 to 4.2.0, the bundle install command is successful, but when I start up server with "rails s", it reports the following error

```
activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- raven/sidekiq (LoadError)
```

I suspect this error is related to 'sidekiq' gem which I used to queue background job or 'sentry-raven' gem which is used by heroku addon to send any system error.

I tried to remove these 2 suspicious gems, but it didn't work.

How could I solve this?

Comment: when you removed the gems from your Gemfile, you bundled again right?  Also do you have anything in an initializer that is calling them. Also does your gemfile have sidekiq or sentry-raven locked to a specific version

Comment: I removed my Gemfile.lock before bundle install, and also I don't lock sentry-raven and sidekiq gem to a specific version. as I can see from new lock file, they are updated as well. sentry-rave (0.12.2), sidekiq (3.3.0)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you use [sidekiq monitoring](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring). Do determine it, open routes.rb, and found here something like

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```

Related to [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/814#issuecomment-17837929) issue, you need to add `sinatra` gem to your Gemfile.
e.g.

```
gem 'sinatra', require: nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error after my sentry-raven gem got upgraded from 0.6.x to 0.13.x when I did a `bundle upgrade`.

I bypassed this error by removing the `require 'raven/sidekiq'` line in my `config/initializers/raven.rb` and have `rails s` command run successfully.

I followed the document of sentry-raven to add the `require 'raven/sidekiq'` in my initializer files when I was working with its version 0.6.0. Now for version 0.13.x it seems not needed any longer.

Hope this helps.